# KeyboardInterrupt suppressed in Windows but not Linux

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, interrupt

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import threading
import time


def thread():
    print("thread:") 
    time.sleep(100)

def main():
    print("main:")
    t = threading.Thread(target=thread)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    print("main: thread started")
    t.join()
    print("main: joined, now exiting")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`KeyboardInterrupt` (but not `SIGINT`) is suppressed on Windows during `t.join()::_wait_for_tstate_lock`, whether run through `cmd.exe` or PowerShell (which launches `C:\Windows\py.exe`). On the other hand, this works as expected on Linux. Tested on Python 3.9.7 and 3.12. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

*edit:* Whereas this works as expected on all systems:

```py
def main():
    print("main:")
    try:
        time.sleep(100)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("main: caught keyboard interrupt")
```

Comment: Might be related to [\[Python-Dev\] Interrupt thread.join() with Ctrl-C / KeyboardInterrupt on Windows](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-August/148800.html) and [threading.Lock.acquire() not interruptible on Windows #74157](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/74157).